# Google play API to update in-app product prices

Tags: android, python, google-api

I am using the google-api-python-client to manage play store in-app products.

I can publish a product with a sub list of prices:

```
  _country_codes = [{'country': 'AU', 'currency': 'AUD'}, {'country': 'US', 'currency': 'USD'},
                  {'country': 'CA', 'currency': 'CAD'}, {'country': 'GB', 'currency': 'GBP'},
                  {'country': 'IE', 'currency': 'EUR'}, {'country': 'NZ', 'currency': 'NZD'},
                  {'country': 'AT', 'currency': 'EUR'}, {'country': 'BE', 'currency': 'EUR'},
                  {'country': 'CY', 'currency': 'EUR'}, {'country': 'EE', 'currency': 'EUR'},
                  {'country': 'FI', 'currency': 'EUR'}, {'country': 'DE', 'currency': 'EUR'},
                  {'country': 'GR', 'currency': 'EUR'}, {'country': 'IT', 'currency': 'EUR'},
                  {'country': 'LT', 'currency': 'EUR'}, {'country': 'LU', 'currency': 'EUR'},
                  {'country': 'NL', 'currency': 'EUR'}, {'country': 'SK', 'currency': 'EUR'},
                  {'country': 'SI', 'currency': 'EUR'}, {'country': 'ES', 'currency': 'EUR'},
                  {'country': 'FR', 'currency': 'EUR'}, {'country': 'PT', 'currency': 'EUR'}]
```

I call the API with autoConvertMissingPrices=True to also set rest of the prices. This all seems fine.

But when I try and updated this product with the same sub list using the update method I get an error from the API: Prices defined for regions not targeted by the app

I have carefully checked the list of countries and my sub list is a subset of where the app is avaliable.

What am I doing wrong?